# Ребята помогите пожалуйста решить проблему

Tags: php, yii

Выдаёт вот такую ошибку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/u0432298/depozithour.com/protected/modules/ulogin/components/UloginUserIdentity.php
>   on line 3

Сам код:

```
<?php
1 if (User::model()->findByAttributes(array('email'=>$uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('email'))) === null)
2 $user->email = $uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('email');
3 $username = $uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('first_name') . explode('@', $uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('email'))[0];
4 $usernameClear =  preg_replace('/[^A-z0-9]/', '', substr($username, 0, 20));
?>
```

Comment: версия PHP какая?

Comment: PHP Версия 5.3.

Comment: Ну я так и подумал. Решение написал в ответе

Answer (score 3, accepted):

проблема вот тут: `explode('@', $uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('email'))[0]`.

Так можно делать начиная с *PHP 5.4*. Если версия ниже, то надо складывать результат выполнения функции в переменную и только потом брать индекс:

```
$explodeArr = explode('@', $uloginModel->getAuthDataItem('email'));
$data = $explodeArr[0];
```

Выход:

1. Либо делать через промежуточную переменную
2. Обновить версию *PHP* (всё-таки давно уж на дворе **7** версия)

Comment: Спасибо Вам огромнейшее Алексей

Comment: @ГаленкоСветлана: Если вам ответ помог, отметьте его галочкой (слева от ответа).